# LFR in python-igraph 0.7.1.post.6

Tags: python, windows-10, benchmarking, igraph, detection

I recently installed python-igraph (version=0.7.1.post6 on windows 10) and I would like to generate networks with communities using LFR benchmark, but I didn't find the specific function to do that.

Is there a function (in igraph) that create LFR benchmark? If not, are there any other recommended  modules that enables generating such graphs (and contain SOTA community detection algorithms as in igraph)?

Thanks,
Gal

Answer (score 0):

```
from networkx.algorithms.community import LFR_benchmark_graph
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, it is defined inside the `networkx` package and this means that you can import it to `igraph`. A minimum working example would go like this.

```
import igraph as ig
from networkx.algorithms import community

def import_nx_network(net):
    graph = ig.Graph(n=net.number_of_nodes(), directed=False)
    graph.add_edges(net.edges())

    return graph

def LFR_graph(N, τ1, τ2, μ, **kwargs):
     net = community.LFR_benchmark_graph(N, τ1, τ2, μ, **kwargs)
     graph = import_nx_network(net)

     return graph
```